# How to fetch saved array from a file & access it like an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, file

I have a file, in which I saved data in array format and later I want to read this data into a variable and this variable must behave like an array.

Suppose I have a file on my pc : **C:/test.txt** and it contains an array :

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => John
    [last_name] => Doe
    [email] => johndoe@gmail.com
)
```

Now I am fetching this data using below method :

```
$myfile = fopen("C:/test.txt", "r");
$test = fread($myfile,filesize("C:/test.txt"));
```

Now when I print **$test** it shows the data like array but when I check the datatype of this variable then it shows **String**.

I have also converted this variable into array using type casting :

```
$test1 = (Array) $test;
```

But when tried to fetch any index from **$test1** then it show Illegal string error.

So can somebody help me out.

Comment: Did you try to get the data type after converting???

Comment: Yes I tried and after converting it shows datatype as array but still couldn't get any index from new variable.

Comment: Could you save it as a JSON instead? `{"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Doe", "email": "johndoe@gmail.com"}`

Answer (score 0):

C:/test.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'first_name' => null,
    'last_name' => null,
    'email' => 'new',
);
```

another file:

```
<?php
$array = inclde('C:/test.php');
```

Or save json in file `C:/test.json`

```
{"first_name":null,"last_name":null,"email":"new"}
```

and in another file:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('C:/test.json');
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: Thanks to answer but I can't include files as there will be 100s files that will be stored and will be fetched later.

Comment: You can save your 100 files in json format, and after that do `$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('C:/pathToFile.json'));`.

Comment: @Ankit  its almoust your code - `$myfile = "C:/test.txt";
$array = inclde($myfile);`

Comment: @VladimirKovpak Yeh, when I tried using json_decode it is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $file = "C:/test.txt";
    $document = fopen($file,'r');
    $contents = fread($document, filesize($file));
    fclose($document);
```

this will give you a array $contents

```
    print_r($contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
// $myarray is the array
file_put_contents('my_file', serialize($myarray));

// Later ...
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents('my_file'));
```

You can guess what [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) does. But read more in docs to learn more specifically.

@VladimirKovpak 's answer will work too, but for simple arrays. Using serialization, you can save nearly any object, and get it back.

If you need more control over serialization process, look into magic methods `__sleep` and `__wakeup` from [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).